# Using pandas pivot_table function hangs up in Python 2.7.2

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I'm using pandas for the first time, working through the 10-minute intro at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html.  Keen to use the pivot_table features. Using Python 2.7.2 and pandas 0.11.0.

After creating the example data frames, I run the pivot_table function calls by copy/paste from the 10 min intro into iPython .. and nothing happens. Ctrl-c shows it stops consistently at:

```
    422         while com._long_prod(sizes) >= 2 ** 63:
    423             i = len(sizes)
--> 424             while com._long_prod(sizes[:i]) >= 2 ** 63:
    425                 i -= 1
    426
```

This happens no matter what is in the dataframe, as I've used other examples and I have run the pivot_table against my own data imported with read_table() function.

Where do I start to debug this?

Comment: So running [97-99] fails? This works ok for me in 0.11.0, how did you install pandas?

Comment: can you paste code for call of `pivot_table`

Comment: I installed pandas with "pip install pandas" into a virtualenv. running on mac.  call to pivot_table is: pd.pivot_table(df,values='D',rows=['A','B'], cols=['C']) with df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

Comment: and dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)

Comment: also, the code above (lines 422-426) are in pandas: /Users/rmschne/.virtualenv/rmspython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.pyc in _long_prod(vals)

Comment: That's strange, that's how I've install 0.11.0 (and it works), but perhaps worth raising an [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues). Just to confirm just running [97] and [99] causes this?

Comment: Yes, running [97] and [980 from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html (prefixed by importing pandas and numpy). I'll report. thanks.